# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java

I am currently doing a project on steganography using discrete Wavelet Transform.I have already written the code and compiled it.However I am facing some exceptions.Kindly help me interpret the exceptions.
The exception is as follows

```
        Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at DWT.dwtFunc(Steganography.java:292)
        at TextInput.actionPerformed(Steganography.java:252)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am new in Stack Overflow.Forgive me if I have made any mistake while posting the question.
Thank You

Re:
Sorry Sir I am still getting acquainted to the rules of the forum.

The code for detection of skin region in an image is

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
    import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.lang.*;

    public class demo2
    {

        public void skindet()
        {
            float[] hsvval;
            float hue,sat,val;
            int counter = 0;
            String[] skinpixel = new String[200000];
            int scount = 0;
            try
            {

                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("lena.png"));
                int[][] rgb=new int[550][550];
                int w = image.getWidth();
                int h = image.getHeight();
                hsvval=new float[3];
                int red,green,blue;
                for (int i=0;i<w;i++) 
                {
                    for (int j=0;j<h;j++)
                    {
                        rgb[i][j] =image.getRGB(i,j);
                        red=(rgb[i][j] >> 16) & 0xff;
                        green=(rgb[i][j] >> 8) & 0xff;
                        blue=(rgb[i][j]) & 0xff;
                        float[] values = Color.RGBtoHSB(red,green,blue,null);
                        for(int s=0;s<3;s++)
                        {
                            hsvval[counter]=values[s];
                            counter++;
                        }
                        hue=hsvval[0];
                        sat=hsvval[1];
                        val=hsvval[2];
                        if(hue>0 && hue<0.11 && sat>0.2 && sat<0.7)
                        {
                            String xcor=Integer.toString(i);
                            String ycor=Integer.toString(j);
                            skinpixel[scount]=xcor;
                            scount++;
                            skinpixel[scount]=ycor;
                            scount++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                int length=skinpixel.length;
                for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
                    System.out.println(skinpixel[i]+"\n");

            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {

            demo2 dem=new demo2();
            dem.skindet();
        }

    }
```

The exception is

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at demo2.skindet(demo2.java:44)
        at demo2.main(demo2.java:79)

Thank You for replying.Regards

Answer (score 2):

It means that you're calling `Integer.parseInt` from line 292 of `Steganography.java` (which unusually appears to hold a class called `DWT` rather than `Steganography`), but you're providing a null value.

It looks like this is in response to some action being performed on a text field.

We can't really tell a lot more without seeing your code - you need to work out *why* the value is null.

EDIT: Okay, now that it's changed to a completely different error, this is the problem:

```
int counter = 0;

hsvval=new float[3];
...
for (int i=0;i<w;i++) 
{
    for (int j=0;j<h;j++)
    {
        ...
        for(int s=0;s<3;s++)
        {
            hsvval[counter]=values[s];
            counter++;
        }
        ...          
    }
}
```

So the *first* time the inner loop is executed, it's fine - but on the second iteration of the middle loop (j = 1), you haven't reset `counter`, so it's 3 - which is out of range. You've got the same problem with `scount` later.

If you declare and initialize `count` and `scount` *just before they're used* in the inner loop, it's fine.

Comment: Thank You for replying.Should I post my code?Its around 800 lines so I thought it would be better off posting the exception.

Comment: @user1320483: Well ideally you'd perform diagnostics yourself given the information so far, and if you're stuck you could post a *short* but complete program to demonstrate the problem (and only the problem). That wouldn't need to be 800 lines long.

Comment: I have fixed the array index out of bounds.However I have replaced the String with ArrayList.However,the question still remains as to why my previous approach did not work.Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thanks a ton sir.Feeling dumb.